# Flutter Radio button text "kg" align problem?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, radio-button, row

[image: IMAGE LINK]

As you can see in above picture ***"kg"*** text has huge **gap**.
but the **height** `text field` widget is perfect.
And it shows the following error.

> Exception caught by widgets library
>
> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

Kindly let me know what is the problem

(I'm new to flutter)

```
      Material(
      elevation: 30.0,
      shadowColor: Colors.grey,
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 375,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),           
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 300,
          width: 500,
          child: Expanded(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: TextField(                         
                      controller: weightcon,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 30,
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: 'Weight',
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: 
                           BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            width: 2.0,
                          ),
                        ),             
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: 
                           BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            // color: Colors.redAccent[100],
                            color: Colors.black54,
                            width: 2.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (weightval) {
                        print('First text field: $weightval');
                        globals.weightvalue = 
                       double.parse(weightval);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 130,
                  width: 30,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                          width: 30,
                          height: 50,
                          child: Flexible(
                            child: SizedBox(
                                child: Radio(
                              value: 0,
                              groupValue: 1,
                              onChanged: (value) {},
                            )),
                          )),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 30,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                          child: Flexible(
                        child: Text("KG"),
                      ),),
                      Flexible(
                        child: SizedBox(
                            width: 30,
                            height: 25,
                            child: Radio(
                              value: 1,
                              groupValue: 1,
                              onChanged: (value) {},
                            )),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 30,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                          child: Flexible(
                        child: Text("LB"),
                      ),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Can you include parent widget of `Material`?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the height for sizedbox of radioButton, height takes the extra space

```
Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                              width: 30,
                              child: Flexible(
                                child: SizedBox(
                                    child: Radio(
                                  value: 0,
                                  groupValue: 1,
                                  onChanged: (value) {},
                                )),
                              )),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 30,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                              child: Flexible(
                            child: Text("KG"),
                          ),),
                          Flexible(
                            child: SizedBox(
                                width: 30,
                                child: Radio(
                                  value: 1,
                                  groupValue: 1,
                                  onChanged: (value) {},
                                )),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 30,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                              child: Flexible(
                            child: Text("LB"),
                          ),),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Do have to wrap column with row

Comment: Most probably it's not need

Comment: Thanks for answering then how do I add radio widget horizontally in text field without  Row widget?

Comment: Inside column bind radio button and text with row

Answer (score 1):

You used the `Expanded` Widget the wrong way! It must be the children of a `Flex` Widget (`Row, Column, ListView, GridView, Wrap,...`). As you can see, you wrote:

```
Expanded(
child: Row( // this is where the error pointing at
),
),
```

So to fix it, remove that `Expanded` Widget and use it as parent of the widgets in side the `Row` Widget. This is an example:

```
Row(
children: [
  Expanded( // Expanded Widget inside children parameter of Row Widget
child: Widget1(),
),
Expanded(
child: Widget2(),
),
],
),
```